# Getting Contacts numbers

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am having problem getting the number of contact that i have selected. In my app I call the built in application for contacts as a new activity, when you choose a contact the activity returns his name, now I need it to return all the numbers that the user entered for that contact. I found the code in some tutorial on the internet... Here is the code

This is how i call the contact activity

```
mSuspectButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_suspect);

mSuspectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CONTACT);
            }
        });
```

This is how i get the name of the selected contact:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            // Specify which fields you want your query to return
            // values for.
            String[] queryFields = new String[] { 
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
            // Perform your query - the contactUri is like a "where"
            // clause here
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri,
                    queryFields, null, null, null);
            // Double-check that you actually got results
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            c.close();
            return;
        }
        // Pull out the first column of the first row of data -
        // that is your suspect's name.
        c.moveToFirst();
        String suspect = c.getString(0);
        mCrime.setSuspect(suspect);
        mSuspectButton.setText(suspect);
        c.close();
    }
}
```

So please can anyone help, I really don't understand how these works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your onActivityResult, this will return you the selected number

```
    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){ 
super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(reqCode){
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()){
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    String hasPhone =
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Write this code to fetch all contact numbers and names.

2) Add them in separate arraylists.

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext())
            {
                String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll(" ", "");
                alContactNames.add(name);
                alContactNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
            }
            phones.close();
```

3) make listview in your app with custom adapter. In each list item, there needs to be the contact number , contact name and check box for selection.

this will solve your problem.

Comment: So I can't call the built in app for contacts and than from there to get the number of the selected contact? Just like i'm doing for the names of contacts